# Why does Visual Studio Code keep loading the PowerShell extension?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-7.3

[image]

Loading the PowerShell extension will not report an error, as if the thread is blocked。I tried to roll back the version of the PowerShell module and reinstall the module, but I couldn't solve it, and I was stuck in this place all the time.

The debug log is as follows:

```
2023/4/1 10:01:40 [NORMAL] - Visual Studio Code v1.77.0 64-bit

2023/4/1 10:01:40 [NORMAL] - Creating log directory at: 'file:///c%3A/Users/Jason/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode.powershell/logs/1680314500-aecc12d4-f24b-445a-afdd-f43d957b9a051680314497951'

2023/4/1 10:01:40 [NORMAL] - PowerShell Extension v2023.3.3

2023/4/1 10:01:40 [NORMAL] - Operating System: Windows 64-bit

2023/4/1 10:01:40 [NORMAL] - Language server starting --

2023/4/1 10:01:40 [NORMAL] -     PowerShell executable: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe

2023/4/1 10:01:40 [NORMAL] -     PowerShell args: -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Import-Module 'c:\Users\Jason\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2023.3.3\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\PowerShellEditorServices.psd1'; Start-EditorServices -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '2023.3.3' -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode') -BundledModulesPath 'c:\Users\Jason\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2023.3.3\modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -StartupBanner "PowerShell Extension v2023.3.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/vscode-powershell
Type 'help' to get help.
" -LogLevel 'Normal' -LogPath 'c:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode.powershell\logs\1680314500-aecc12d4-f24b-445a-afdd-f43d957b9a051680314497951\EditorServices.log' -SessionDetailsPath 'c:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode.powershell\sessions\PSES-VSCode-22424-827161.json' -FeatureFlags @() 

2023/4/1 10:01:40 [NORMAL] -     PowerShell Editor Services args: Import-Module 'c:\Users\Jason\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2023.3.3\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\PowerShellEditorServices.psd1'; Start-EditorServices -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '2023.3.3' -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode') -BundledModulesPath 'c:\Users\Jason\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2023.3.3\modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -StartupBanner "PowerShell Extension v2023.3.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/vscode-powershell
Type 'help' to get help.
" -LogLevel 'Normal' -LogPath 'c:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode.powershell\logs\1680314500-aecc12d4-f24b-445a-afdd-f43d957b9a051680314497951\EditorServices.log' -SessionDetailsPath 'c:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode.powershell\sessions\PSES-VSCode-22424-827161.json' -FeatureFlags @() 

2023/4/1 10:01:40 [NORMAL] - pwsh.exe started.

2023/4/1 10:01:40 [NORMAL] - Waiting for session file...

2023/4/1 10:01:42 [NORMAL] - Session file found!

2023/4/1 10:01:42 [NORMAL] - pwsh.exe PID: 26044

2023/4/1 10:01:42 [NORMAL] - Language server started.

2023/4/1 10:01:42 [NORMAL] - Connecting to language service on pipe: \\.\pipe\PSES_pzeameiq.jng

2023/4/1 10:01:42 [NORMAL] - Session details: {"status":"started","languageServiceTransport":"NamedPipe","languageServicePipeName":"\\\\.\\pipe\\PSES_pzeameiq.jng","debugServiceTransport":"NamedPipe","debugServicePipeName":"\\\\.\\pipe\\PSES_0lftfipp.zye"}

2023/4/1 10:01:42 [NORMAL] - Language service socket connected.
```

I tried to uninstall the PowerShell module, reinstall, and roll back the old version of the module, but it couldn't be solved.

Comment: [Don't forget to ask your question](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070315-00/?p=27603).

Comment: Sorry, my problem is that PowerShell has been loading modules, and it is still loading after waiting for 30 minutes, which prevents me from using PowerShell to run scripts

Comment: I would think it would be better to go ahead and update your question rather than adding a comment.